# No such DLS method "style" (MarkupBuilder)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I try to build a string in html-format to send it as an E-Mail in a jenkins-pipeline. I have following bit of code:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def html = new MarkupBuilder( writer )

html.table( class: "squishSummary" ) {
    style( type: "text/css" ) {
        mkp.yield( getTableStyle() )
    }
    ...
}

def getTableStyle() {
    ....
}
```

Unfortunately this runs into an error while executing the pipeline: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'style' found among steps [...]` If I'm understanding it correctly the jenkins-server tries to execute the style-command as a jenkins build-step, what reasonably fails. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code works fine:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def html = new MarkupBuilder( writer )

html.table( class: "squishSummary" ) {
    style( type: "text/css" ) {
        mkp.yield("123")
    }
}
println writer
```

however if you declare variable named `style` then you get the error similar to yours

so this code will fail with `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method ...`

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def html = new MarkupBuilder( writer )

def style = "my style1" //just add this line and code fails

html.table( class: "squishSummary" ) {
    style( type: "text/css" ) {
        mkp.yield("123")
    }
}

println writer
```

to solve problem use `delegate` or GString instead of plain method name:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def writer = new StringWriter()
def html = new MarkupBuilder( writer )

def style = "style1"

html.table( class: "squishSummary" ) {
    delegate.style( type: "text/css" ) {
        mkp.yield("123")
    }
    //or like this:
    "${'style'}"( type: "text/css" ) {
        mkp.yield("123")
    }
}

println writer
```